# More than one TaskScheduler and/or ScheduledExecutorService exist within the context

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I've 2 schedulers, one is annotations driven and other normal spring scheduler defined with "task"

but after adding below code to my project context, I'm getting exception :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than one TaskScheduler and/or
>   ScheduledExecutorService  exist within the context. Remove all but one
>   of the beans; or implement the SchedulingConfigurer interface and call
>   ScheduledTaskRegistrar#setScheduler explicitly within the
>   configureTasks() callback. Found the following beans: [myappScheduler,
>   taskScheduler]

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="scanIn" directory="file:${uploadfilepath}"  auto-startup="true" prevent-duplicates="true" filename-regex="^.*\.(csv|xml)$" >
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="60000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="scanIn"  output-channel="scanOut" ref="scanHandler" />

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="scanOut"  directory="file:${inputfiles.archive.path}" delete-source-files="true"/>

<bean id="scanHandler" class="com.rs.ibgt.pf.intg.VirusScanHandler" />
```

please suggest any solution ..

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration adds its own (`taskScheduler`) bean. You need to show the rest of your configuration - it looks like you are trying to auto wire a scheduler; if so, you need to add a `@Qualifier` or give it a name to match the bean you are actually trying to inject (e.g. `myappScheduler`).